# Print out the position in the array and the number at that position

Tags: java, arrays, search

I'm doing an assignment, where i the program supposed to print out the position in the array and the number at that position (by using linear search). Here is what I've got so far, but the output was not what I expected.

Output:

```
Number 0  Linear Search Index At 0
Number 1  Linear Search Index At 1
Number 2  Linear Search Index At 2
Number 2  Linear Search Index At 5
Number 2  Linear Search Index At 7
Number 3  Linear Search Index At 9
Number 3  Linear Search Index At 10
Number 4  Linear Search Index At -1
Number 4  Linear Search Index At 11
Number 5  Linear Search Index At 13
Number 6  Linear Search Index At 16
Number 8  Linear Search Index At 17
Number 8  Linear Search Index At 18
Number 9  Linear Search Index At 19
Number 9  Linear Search Index At -1
Number 9  Linear Search Index At 20
Number 10  Linear Search Index At 21
Number 11  Linear Search Index At -1
Number 12  Linear Search Index At -1
Number 13  Linear Search Index At -1
Number 15  Linear Search Index At 22
Number 16  Linear Search Index At 23
Number 20  Linear Search Index At 24
Number 21  Linear Search Index At 26
Number 22  Linear Search Index At 27
Number 22  Linear Search Index At -1
Number 23  Linear Search Index At 29
Number 24  Linear Search Index At 30
Number 24  Linear Search Index At 32
Number 26  Linear Search Index At -1
Number 27  Linear Search Index At 33
Number 27  Linear Search Index At -1
Number 28  Linear Search Index At -1
Number 30  Linear Search Index At -1
```

Code:

```
    public class LinearSearch {
    public int linearSearch(int[] array, int key) {
        int size = array.length;
        for ( int i = 0; i < size; i++ ) {
            if ( array[i] == key ) {
                return i;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }

    public static void main(String[] arg) {
        int[] array = { 0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 15, 16, 20, 21, 22, 22, 23, 24, 24, 26, 27, 27, 28, 30};

        LinearSearch search = new LinearSearch();
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("Number " + array[i] + " " + " Linear Search Index" +
                search.linearSearch(array, i));
        }
    }

  }
```

Any helps would be great! Thank you!

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: linearSearch() finds the first occurrence of the element and return its index.

Comment: @Benj try replacing `linSearch.linearSearch(array, i))` with `linSearch.linearSearch(array, array[i]))`

Comment: And what is the output you expect?

Comment: @Benj what is your expected out put??

Comment: i suppose updating your print statement will do the task for you -: System.out.println("Number " + i + " " + " Linear Search Index At " +
                linSearch.linearSearch(array, i));

Comment: @Benj posted answer for your acceptance/upvote

Comment: When your array is already sorted, why do you not use the API functionality `Arrays.binarySearch(array, array[i])` instead of your manual `linSearch.linearSearch(array, array[i])`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try replacing `linSearch.linearSearch(array, i))` with `linSearch.linearSearch(array, array[i]))`

```
 public static void main(String[] arg) {
        int[] array = { 0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 15, 16, 20, 21, 22, 22, 23, 24, 24, 26,
                27, 27, 28, 30 };

        MyLinearSearch linSearch = new MyLinearSearch();
        for (int i = 0 ; i < array.length ; i++) {
            System.out.println("Number " + array[i] + " " + " Linear Search Index At "
                    + linSearch.linearSearch(array, array[i]));
        }
    }
```